# screen starts up with lines running across?

Tags: 12.04, graphics, hp-pavilion

I just transferred a HP pavilion dv2000 from windows to Ubuntu 12.04.

When it starts up there there are lines across the screen and after I log in, The mouse can't reach the edge of the screen on the left and if you touch the top of the screen with the cursors, a bar runs top to bottom and stays there as long as it touches the top. If you close and open the screen several times, sometimes it goes away.

i found a suggestion in a forum to check the print out of:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test --print
```

it printed this:

```
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 55 
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 56
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 59
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 58
nvfx_screen_get_param:95 -  Warning: unknown PIPE_CAP 30
OpenGL vendor string:   nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on NV67
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 8.0.4

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Comment: also if i move my mouse to far to the right it will get stuck on the otherside of the scroll bar {its weird will go up and down then but not left and right}, if i move my mouse quickly it wil pop back over and be fine again

Comment: Did you try installing the proprietary nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I also get that in Ubuntu 12.10 Alpha 3 VM. (Don't worry, now I have 12.10 final and that problem is fixed).

The EASIEST way that worked for me is log off the PC and log in again.
Then, you will not see that anymore!
BUT,
if you shut down and start the PC later, you should repeat again (log off the PC and log in again).